# Login website that required enable javascript to login

Tags: c#, winforms

By default, C# can't login to website require javascript must enabled.
example site: wellsfargo.com, starbucks.com

Thanks

Comment: You're not serious with this question are you? oh wait.. there is no question

Comment: And you question is...

Comment: By default, C# can't do anything unless you write the code to do it.  What code have you written and how is it not working as expected?

Answer (score -1):

Install selenium using nuget. Then install the chrome driver. Chrome will handle the javascript side of things and you can just fill in the username and password textboxes.

Comment: Why the downvote? I've assumed viclic can't use those pages using HttpWebRequest / HttpWebRequest because they're doing something fancy in javascript. Using selenium lets you interact with those complex pages.